# Disprove this statement: if $r$ is rational and $s$ is irrational, then $r/s$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I think the answer shown in class included $s = \pi$. Also would it be a valid answer to say $r = 3$ and $s = \frac{1}{0}$, so $\frac{r}{s} = 3\times\frac{0}{1} = 0$ ? Thanks.

Comment: $1/0$ is not a real number.

Comment: Hints: (1) $s=(\frac rs)^{-1}r$; (2) if $x\neq0$ then $x$ is rational if and only if $\frac1x$ is rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a true statement:

Iff $r$ is a nonzero rational and $s$ is irrational, then $r/s$ is irrational.

Proof:

If $r/s$ is rational, then so is $s/r$.
Multiplying by $r, s$ is rational,
a contradiction.

Therefore 
the only way 
your original statement can be false
is if $r$ is zero,
and when
$r=0$ it certainly is false.

Comment: ok this makes alot of sense. So because 0 is rational, I only have to divide 0 by any irrational number such as s = pi or sqrt(2)

Comment: Right. Then the result is zero, which is rational. Note that any irrational is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

$$(r=0)\wedge(s=\pi)\implies(r/s=0\in\mathbb{Q})$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer you give would not be a valid answer. 1/0 is undefined, so trying to define s = 1/0 doesn't make any sense.

Try to find a counter example.

Let us know if this helps set you on your way.